# Remove ViewController from stack

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, stack, mvvmcross

In our App we have a log-in `ViewController A`. On user log-in, a request navigate is automatically called to navigate to the next `ViewController B`. However when this is done we want to remove the log-in `ViewController A` from the stack so the user cannot "go back" to the log-in view but goes back the previous `ViewController` before the log-in instead.

We thought about removing the `ViewController A` from the stack when `ViewController B` is loaded, but is there a better way?

In the Android version of the App we've set `history=no` (if I recall correctly) and then it works.

Is there an similar way to achieve this in MonoTouch and MvvmCross?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up with removing the unwanted viewcontroller from the navigation controller. In `ViewDidDisappear()` of my login `ViewController` I did the following:

```
public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
{
    if (this.NavigationController != null) {
        var controllers = this.NavigationController.ViewControllers;
        var newcontrollers = new UIViewController[controllers.Length - 1];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in controllers) {
            if (item != this) {
                newcontrollers [index] = item;
                index++;
            }

        }
        this.NavigationController.ViewControllers = newcontrollers;
    }
    base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
}
```

This way I way remove the unwanted `ViewController` when it is removed from the view. I am not fully convinced if it is the right way, but it is working rather good.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a common scenario... so much so that we've included two mechanisms inside MvvmCross to allow this....

1. a `ClearTop` parameter available in all ViewModel navigations.
2. a `RequestRemoveBackStep()` call in all ViewModels - although this is currently NOT IMPLEMENTED IN iOS - sorry.
3. If this isn't enough, then a third technique might be to use a custom presenter to help with your display logic.

---

#### To use : 1. a `ClearTop` parameter available in all ViewModel navigations.

To use this, simply include the ClearTop flag when navigating.

This is a boolean flag - so to use it just change:

```
this.RequestNavigate<ChildViewModel>(new {arg1 = val1});
```

to

```
this.RequestNavigate<ChildViewModel>(new {arg1 = val1}, true);
```

For a standard simple navigation controller presenter, this will end up calling `ClearBackStack` before your new view is shown:

```
    public override void ClearBackStack()
    {
        if (_masterNavigationController == null)
            return;

        _masterNavigationController.PopToRootViewController (true);
        _masterNavigationController = null;
    }
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxTouchViewPresenter.cs

If you are not using a standard navigation controller - e.g. if you had a tabbed, modal, popup or split view display then you will need to implement your own presentation logic to handle this.

---

#### You can't: 2. `RequestRemoveBackStep()`.

Sadly it proved a bit awkward to implement this at a generic level for iOS - so currently that method is:

```
    public bool RequestRemoveBackStep()
    {
#warning What to do with ios back stack?
        // not supported on iOS really
        return false;
    }
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/MvxTouchViewDispatcher.cs

Sorry! I've raised a bug against this - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/80

---

#### 3. You can always... Custom ideas

If you need to implement something custom for your iOS app, the best way is to do this through some sort of custom Presenter logic.

There are many ways you could do this.

One example is:

- for any View or ViewModel which needs to clear the previous view, you could decorate the View or ViewModel with a `[Special]` attribute
- in `Show` in your custom `Presenter` in your app, you could watch for that attribute and do the special behaviour at that time

  ```
  public override void Show(MvxShowViewModelRequest request)
  {
      if (request.ViewModelType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SpecialAttribute), true).Any())
      {
          // do custom behaviour here - e.g. pop current view controller
      }

      base.Show(request);
  }
  ```

Obviously other mechanisms might be available - it's just C# and UIKit code at this stage

Comment: Hi Stuart, Thank you for the details. I believed it was a common scenario and hoped there was an easy way to do this. I will try your suggestion with the clearTop Boolean as it is a standard navigation Controller. I will do this first thing in the morning and then share my experience :)

Comment: Hi Stuart, what I missed in your explanation was the call poptorootviewcontroller. What I wanted was only to pop the previous viewcontroller, but you pointed me in the right direction. I ended up removing the unwanted viewcontroller from the navigationcontroller. It seems to work, however I am still not fully convinced it is the right way to go :)

Comment: Hi stuart, sorry for ripping this old thread, but do you have an example where the use of RequestRemoveBackStep() is applied in mono droid? I thought it was similar to RequestNavigate but I am not sure.

Comment: Apology accepted - but I think you need to ask new thought-out questions - SO frowns on discussions in comments.

Comment: I just did, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437545/remove-activity-from-stack-using-mono-droid-and-slodge-mvvmcross

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about mvvm but you can simply Pop the viewcontroller (AC A) without animation and then push the new viewcontoller (AC B) with animation

From within AC A:

```
NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(false);
NavigationController.PushViewController(new ACb(), true);
```