# Remove activity from stack using Mono droid and slodge mvvmcross

Tags: navigation, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to find a way to remove an activity from the stack- We have a flow in our app: activity/viewmodel a -> activity/viewmodel b ->activity/viewmodel c. In c the user have the posibility of choosing a date or go back. If he goes back he should be returned to b. However if he chooses a date he is fowarded to a new instance of activity/viewmodel b and the "old" instance of activity/viewmodel b is obsolete and should be removed.

A suggestion from Stuart Lodge (on a similar thread, just for mono touch) was to use RequestRemoveBackStep() but I am not sure how to use it and I cant find an example.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RequestRemoveBackStep()` method is a member of the `IMvxViewDispatcher` interface and is implemented on some platforms:

```
public interface IMvxViewDispatcher : IMvxMainThreadDispatcher
{
    bool RequestNavigate(MvxShowViewModelRequest request);
    bool RequestClose(IMvxViewModel whichViewModel);
    bool RequestRemoveBackStep();
}
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Interfaces/Views/IMvxViewDispatcher.cs

However, its not entirely simple to always do this... so on Droid, for example, it is currently implemented as:

```
    public bool RequestRemoveBackStep()
    {
        // not supported on Android? Not sure how to do this currently...
        return false;
    }
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewDispatcher.cs

There are issues logged about this functionality - e.g. https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/80 - but it seems likely that this functionality might simply be dropped from future Mvx implementations - especially as it's not very easy to do for every view on every platform.

---

If you need this type of functionality now, then you'll need to find your own way of implementing this functionality... depending on what your specific use case is (sorry - the details of your current use case aren't clear to me from the question).

There are several technical routes available including:

- using `NoHistory` flags
- using `RequestClose(oldviewModel)` calls
- adding logic to your `Presenter`
- using a `Messenger` to request views close themselves.

Comment: Hi Stuart thank you for the suggestions. I ended up using a event to request the views to close. I had hoped to use RequestRemoveBackStep() but I understand it is difficult to implement on all platforms :) In our implementation we now have custom ways of removing views from the stack in both mono touch and mono droid, when it is not enough to use the core implementation.