# How to clear the back / activity stack when showing a new ViewModel

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I would like to clear the back / activity stack when showing a new ViewModel. As far as I could google this I have to set some flags on the Intent which creates the new Activity. So how is this done in mvvmcross?

This app only targets android so if I have to do some android dependant stuff thats fine.

Comment: Why not handle `onBackPressed()` in your Activity? And just stop the user from going back further?

Comment: @orion78fr This actually works. Here is the mvvmcross / monodroid code for the MvxActivity: 
`public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e) { if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) return true; return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e); }`

Comment: @orion78fr Just found out a side Effect of this. Since the Activity where I implemented this is the StartScreen of the App you are no longer able to Exit the Application by pressing back. Not sure if this is going to be a Problem or not.

Comment: If you want to hide the StartScreen activity when back is pressed (in Java): `public void onBackPressed() { this.moveTaskToBack(true); }` In fact not doing this IS a problem, it's a accessibility issue.

Comment: I think it may help to keep searching. There are lots of other questions on this like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474865/mvvmcross-navigate-back-multiple-viewmodels-truncate-navigation-stack - while on an old version, the suggestions at the end of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437545/remove-activity-from-stack-using-mono-droid-and-slodge-mvvmcross/14446678#14446678 are also still valid and useful. Look for info on custom presenters and presentation hints in v3... But also look at java-android questions - understand the Java and the c# will be easy. Stuart (in transit)

Comment: hi thomas...have you done with this?

Comment: @GvSharma we went with the code I posted as a comment